# Interpreting coefficients of rugarch package in R

Tags: r

How do I interpret the coefficients of t garch in the rugarch package?

which is the parameter for dummy variable? and also which one is the coefficient for arch and garch parameter

I have the results however I am confused the dummy variable parameter

```
spec = rugarch::ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "fGARCH", garchOrder = c(1,1), submodel = "TGARCH"), mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1,1), include.mean = TRUE),distribution.model = "std")

fgarch.t = rugarch::ugarchfit(data = daily_ret_developed_monthly, 
                              spec = spec, solver = "solnp")

fgarch.t@fit$coef



 mu           ar1           ma1         omega        alpha1         beta1         eta11         shape 
 0.0008409928  0.8470773484 -0.8553335918  0.0001488852  0.0816275946  0.9317382995 -0.1644055512  3.6871423500
```

Comment: what is your `daily_ret_developed_monthly`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ***short*** answer is:

1. `eta11` is the rotation parameter, *i.e.* when you do decomposition of the residuals inside the equation for the conditional variance, you can allow a *shift* (`eta2`) or/and *rotation* (`eta1`) in the *news impact curve*.
2. `alpha1` is the `ARCH(q)` parameter. In your case, `q` is 1.
3. `beta1` is the `GARCH(p)` parameter. In your case, `p` is 1.

***Additional information***:

You are looking at the following *family* of `GARCH` equations, collectively called `fGARCH` in `rugarch` package:

---

[image]

---

For *threshold* `GARCH` (`tGARCH`) models:

[image]

and

[image]

while

[image]

You have also `mu` parameter estimated since you have selected `include.mean = TRUE`. The parameter `shape` is a numeric value denoting the shape parameter of the conditional distribution of standardized residuals `z_t`. Lastly, the parameter `omega` in your model is the *variance intercept parameter*.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot. I reached the same conclusion by a unorthodox route. I did the same analysis in eviews and compared the coefficients. However, thanks for the help

Comment: If it answers your question,  will you accept it please?  Thanks.

Comment: Hi, sure will. Please let me know how to

Comment: On the top left corner of my answer you see upvote sign and check sign.  Use both of them.